# PSQL Group by multiple conditions on same row

Tags: sql, database, group-by, count, psql

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
Letter  Color  
A       Red    
A       Blue    
B       Red          
C       Red
C       Red
```

What I would like to achieve is the below output format:

```
Letter   Red   Blue
A        1     1
B        1     0
C        2     0
```

Tried below:

```
SELECT letter, red, blue FROM (
SELECT letter, count(*) AS red from letters where color = 'red'
GROUP BY letter
UNION
SELECT letter, count(*) AS blue from letters where color = 'blue'
GROUP BY letter
) GROUP BY letter
```

Can anyone help? Please note that I can't add any tablefunc or similar to DB.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `UNION` with `SELECT` as red, blue values and get the `MAX()` values of red, blue `GROUP BY letter`

```
SELECT letter, MAX(red) AS red, MAX(blue) AS blue 
FROM (
    SELECT letter, count(*) AS red, 0 AS blue 
    FROM letters 
    WHERE color = 'red'
    GROUP BY letter
    UNION
    SELECT letter, 0 AS red, count(*) AS blue 
    FROM letters 
    WHERE color = 'blue'
    GROUP BY letter
) alias_name 
GROUP BY letter
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest method is conditional aggregation:

```
select letter,
       sum(case when color = 'Red' then 1 else 0 end) as red,
       sum(case when color = 'Blue' then 1 else 0 end) as blue
from letters
group by letter
order by letter;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try group on Letter to get counts separately and then join

```
select T1.Letter, CASE WHEN Red is NULL THEN 0 ELSE Red END AS Red , CASE WHEN Blue is NULL THEN 0 ELSE Blue END AS Blue   
from 
(select Letter, count(*) as Red from letters where Color = 'Red' group by Letter) T1 
full join 
(select Letter, count(*) as Blue from letters where Color = 'Blue' group by Letter) T2 
on T1.Letter = T2.Letter;
```